# Implement closed B-Spline interpolation of datapoints

Tags: computational-geometry, spline, bspline, cubic-spline, nurbs

I have a set of 3D points which I am trying to interpolate using a **pth-degree** B-Spline. I have implemented the algorithm described here [https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-INT-global.html](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-INT-global.html) so that the curve passes through the datapoints. Also, the curve I have has the 1st point equal to the last points, since it is a closed curve.

Now, I have implemented the interpolation algorithm for the **clamped** case, where the 1st **p** and last **p** knots are 0 and 1, respectively, and have **p+1** multiplicity. However, I am struggling to do the same for the **closed** case, where I want the curve to be periodic.

I have successfully transformed the **clamped** (or open) curve representation I obtained into a closed representation by modifying the knots, according to the **Control Point Wrapping** algorithm described here: [https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve-closed.html](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/spline/B-spline/bspline-curve-closed.html)

However, I have tried to do the same with the **Knot Wrapping** algorithm, but with no success. They say to wrap the last knots with the first ones, but the knot vector is supposed to be a sequence of nondecreasing real numbers, so that can't be. I have also tried to do the wrapping by extending the knot vector past 1 for the knots corresponding to the wrapped control points, while keeping the knot deltas in the beginning of the knot vector, but that didn't work either.

Now I am wondering if I should solve the system of equations already knowing the final curve has to be closed, instead of trying to transform the **clamped** curve into a **closed** one. Would anyone know how to correctly implement this, or know where to point me in the right direction?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it adds a new b-spline, instead of moving one part of the old to make it closed.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).